# kknn - Iris example - what is the value of k?

Tags: r, knn

I'm trying to learn how to use kknn and am working through the [iris example in the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kknn/versions/1.3.1/topics/kknn). 
Meanwhile, my homework requires me to apply kknn to a dataset and iteratively supply k values and test to find the best one.  
While supplying a value for k is an option for the function, the iris example produces a solution without a k value being supplied:

```
iris.kknn <- kknn(Species~., iris.learn, iris.valid, distance = 1,
                  kernel = "triangular")
```

How do we determine from the resulting kknn object what k value was used to produce the results?  Does it use an arbitrary default value, or does it somehow optimise to pick a best value for k?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value of `k` = 7. You can see that in the **Usage** section of the documentation to which you linked, or by typing `?kknn`.

You can determine what `k` was used from the number of columns in `iris.kknn$C` (or `iris.kknn$W`, `iris.kknn$D` or `iris.kknn$CL`).

```
ncol(iris.kknn$C)
[1] 7
```

Comment: I hadn't realised the values supplied in the Usage section were defaults, I guess duh, what else would they be !? Thanks.

Comment: I guess it is not immediately obvious when you're starting out. If no parameter is supplied and the function works, then there has to be a default and it should be documented. You can also see the defaults using `args(kknn)`.